# Magento 2 Rest api POST JSON TypeProcessor error

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

Have a problem with Magento2 rest APIs. I try to import some data to DB table im my module. I wrote rest api, that gets a JSON array and insert it in database table, but when i try to send this array

**cities.json:**

```
 {
        "cities":
                    [
                        {
                            "id":7,
                            "name":"Kyiv",
                            "ref":"a9280688-94c0-11e3-b441-0050568002cf",
                            "area_ref":"7150813b-9b87-11de-822f000c2965ae0e"
                        },
                        {
                            "id":10,
                            "name":"Moscow",
                            "ref":"96b8d7a4-be42-11e3-9fa0-0050568002cf",
                            "area_ref":"7150813d-9b87-11de-822f000c2965ae0e"
                        },
                        {
                            "id":11,
                            "name":"London",
                            "ref":"f7062316-4078-11de-b509-001d92f78698",
                            "area_ref":"7150812b-9b87-11de-822f000c2965ae0e"
                        }
                    ]
    }
```

i've got an error:

> {"message":"Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file.
>   Report ID: webapi-580e2fd764b10"}

in log file:
**exception.log**

> Next Exception: Report ID: webapi-580e2fd764b10; Message: Notice:
>   Array to string conversion in
>   /home/workuser/Projects/magentov/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php
>   on line 505 in
>   /home/workuser/Projects/magentov/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:195
>   Stack trace:
>   /home/workuser/Projects/magentov/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php(139):
>   Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->_critical(Object(Exception))
>   /home/workuser/Projects/magentov/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(219):
>   Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->maskException(Object(Exception))
>   /home/workuser/Projects/magentov/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(37):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>   /home/workuser/Projects/magentov/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>   /home/workuser/Projects/magentov/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
>   /home/workuser/Projects/magentov/pub/index.php(37):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
>   {main} [] []

I'me looked into **TypeProcessor.php** on *505* line. When i disable this if:

```
if ($value !== null && !settype($value[$key], $arrayItemType)) {
                    throw new SerializationException(
                        new Phrase(
                            'Invalid type for value: "%value". Expected Type: "%type".',
                            ['value' => $value, 'type' => $type]
                        )
                    );
                }
```

everything work fine. I'll get json by POST, decode it and insert all data into DB table, but how can i do it without changing **TypeProcessor.php**?

I send JSON by curl:

```
curl -X POST "http://magentov.dev/index.php/rest/V1/NP/cities" -H "Authorization: Bearer uoj2to52kkn46hmdw0m5gh0oax7uoed9" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '@cities.json'
```

Please, help me.

Comment: did you get some solution for this @Illia Arefyev .. I am facing the same problem..

Comment: @MohammadMujassam yes. I just used auth bearer.

Comment: @MohammadMujassam i'll add full answer here in a few days. Maybe tommorow.  Unfortunately, dont have enough time now.

Comment: pass public function setData(array $dealermaster);